# AppleShowAllFiles does not show hidden files

Tags: finder, macos

I use OS X 10.8, I type the following

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
killall Finder
```

but still I cannot see any hidden files like **.bash_history**, **.Trash**, **.cups**, **.gem** etc. in user directory.

Answer (score 20):

The bundle identifier is `com.apple.finder` in lowercase.

`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` would also write the setting as a string, but it doesn't usually matter though.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'
```

Comment: Worked for me on 10.8.4

Answer (score 1):

Please use `defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles` to read current status.

Note that **it's different** to use command with root user (e.g. sudo) or standard user and use **com.apple.finder** with **Finder** in lowercase.

For **Hide hidden** files
use `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 0` from current user terminal window *not* using `sudo` or `sudo su` command.

For **Show hidden** files 
use `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1`

Then relaunch Finder using `killall Finder`

Tested on OS X 10.8.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I tried Lauri's solution, and had intermittent success. I found that my particular problem was that I was sometimes running the command from root. Running it from standard permissions proved consistently successful, where running it from root proved consistently unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 Macs, both running 10.8.3.  I was able to use the

```
 defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

suggestion on my Mac Mini with success, but it did not work on the macbook pro no matter how many times (or which method I used) to restart Finder.  When I used the "boolean" method, it worked for the macbook the first time.  The macbook is a 2010 unit, and the mini from 2012, but all that should be only in the OS, and not related to hardware.  very odd, but thanks very much for posting both options.  I was beginning to drive myself crazy trying to see hidden files on the laptop.  I even used "sudo" for the "AppleShowAllFiles" method, thinking it was a permissions thing, but that did not help.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `-boolean` option:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean TRUE
killall Finder
```

`YES` is not automatically interpreted as a boolean, but as a string.

Comment: no..doesn't work: "Unexpected argument TRUE; leaving defaults unchanged. "

Comment: @KMC Ok, what about the `-boolean` version? Sorry, I have no 10.8 system on which to test.

Comment: same error.  I want to go back to 10.6...

Comment: @KMC Which OS X version are you using, 10.6 oder 10.8?

Comment: i though my question stated clearly 10.8 (the first line)

Comment: Oops, @LauriRanta is absolutely right regarding the position of the `-boolean` flag! Lauri, would you prefer to edit my answer (I don't know if it brings you any reputation)? You're also absolutely welcome to write your own answer  :)

Comment: You can always edit your own answers.